# Using Common Header Files in eVC++ 3

Tags: c++, include, dev-c++, evc

I'm learning C++ and i have the eVT(eMbedded Visual Tools) installed in my computer, because of the eVB 3(eMbedded Visual Basic) for my VB pocket programs, but i'm learning C++, then i want to use the eVC++ 3 for develop some command line aplications, then only to test i created an HelloWorld aplication, just for test, but when i try to compile it gave me this error:

> Fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'iostream': No such file or directory
>   Error executing clarm.exe.

Remember that i can't update to eVC++ 4, because i want to build programs for Windows CE 3.1
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recently i see some eVC++ example and as i can see, eVC++(remember: Plus Plus) only uses C(Without ++) code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the path to the directory where `ostream` file resides to the list of the compiler include paths (usually `-I` directive).

Comment: Either edit the "Addintional include directives" in C++ section of the project properties or, if you start the compiler from the command line use -I command-line option.

Comment: Is there a graphical interface and a project? Or do you just edit files and then start compilation from the command-line?

Comment: There's a minor problem: I've never in my whole development experience have seen the eVC++3. However the problem you face is quite simple and typical but the details you provide are very vague. It doesn't matter whether the program will be command-line or not. I ask you how you start compilation - from IDE or from the command line?

Comment: Then there must be some setting in the IDE that tells the compiler where to look for header files. It should be called somehow like "include directories". Alternatively there could be an option for setting the additional command-line parameters.

Comment: But i searched in the include path of the eVC++ 3 and there are no files called iostream or ostream or istream, only some WinCE include files.

Comment: First you need to find where the iostream file actually resides - just search the entire drive. Then when you know the folder add this folder path to the list of the include directories in the compiler settings.